# AngularJS $http.get JSON file returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, json

I am trying to get data from a JSON file to display in my AngularJS app using $http.get(...). When I run an alert with JSON.stringify, the alert says 'undefined'. Here is my code:

JS

```
var pplApp = angular.module('pplApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'utilServices' ]);

  pplApp.controller('pplCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('people.json').then(function(data) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(data.People));
      $scope.peoples = data.People;
    });
  });
```

JSON

```
{
"People": [
  {
    "name": "Andrew Amernante",
    "rating": 3,
    "img": "http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200",
  "Description": "Gluten­free cray cardigan vegan. Lumbersexual pork belly blog, fanny pack put a bird on it selvage",
  "Likes": [
    "Dogs",
    "Long walks on the beach",
    "Chopin",
    "Tacos"
  ],
  "Dislikes": [
    "Birds",
    "Red things",
    "Danish food",
    "Dead Batteries"
  ]
}
]
}
```

What am I missing?

Update: Here is my app in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Z2ZLniETlZD9Jaz7QHWY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result is a response object (not the data itself). You can access the data as `response.data`

```
pplApp.controller('pplCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('people.json').then(function(response) {
      alert(JSON.stringify(response.data.People));
      $scope.peoples = response.data.People;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not use  dot operator with JSON.stringify  since its just a string, change it as,

```
  alert(JSON.stringify(data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here ***data*** is a JSON string not object, so you can not use ***data.People***, instead you just need to pass ***data*** to ***JSON.parse***.

```
var pplApp = angular.module('pplApp', [ 'ngAnimate', 'ngSanitize', 'utilServices' ]);
  pplApp.controller('pplCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http.get('people.json').then(function(data) {
      var response = JSON.parse(data);
      $scope.peoples = response.People;
    });
});
```

I checked with your json string and works using following code.

```
var json = '{"People": [{"name": "Andrew Amernante","rating": 3,"img": "http://www.fillmurray.com/200/200","Description": "Gluten­free cray cardigan vegan. Lumbersexual pork belly blog, fanny pack put a bird on it selvage","Likes": ["Dogs","Long walks on the beach","Chopin","Tacos"],"Dislikes": ["Birds","Red things","Danish food","Dead Batteries"]}]}';
var response = JSON.parse(json);
$scope.peoples = response.People;
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice, but when I set up the response variable and then pass data to JSON.parse, I get a Syntax Error in the console: Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1